# Blend4Web loading screen

Tags: export, webgl, blend4web

I am currently making a project using blend4web, I am quite new to this plugin so please help me out. Upon exporting my project the plugin seem to generate a loading screen with b4w logo, is it possible to change this loading screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to modify the preloader of the "standard" web player without coding. Developers can customize preloaders by using the Blend4Web API: https://www.blend4web.com/api_doc/module-preloader.html